# how to connenct remote mysql connection in cpanel

Tags: java, mysql, cpanel

I am trying to connect MySQL database remotely from my local pc since 2 weeks but I failed . www.hdvoiz.com this is where I created my database and I am using Cpanel admin panel . please help me .

- here is the Error msg

  java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'hdvoiz_user'@'95.218.172.137' (using password: YES)
- here is my code

  package rmotedb;

  ```
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.SQLException;

  public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

      try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

      System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
          e.printStackTrace();
          return;
      }

      System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
      Connection connection = null;

      try {
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://hdvoiz.com:3306/hdvoiz_loy";
          String username = "hdvoiz_user";
          String password = "**********";
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

      } catch (SQLException e) {
          System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
          e.printStackTrace();
          return;
      }

      if (connection != null) {
          System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
      } else {
          System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
      }
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, Mysql connection works based on IP addresses. So you have to add your ip address with the mentioned credentials to access it remotely.

Comment: @Sercan Ozdemir could you pls write one example.?

Answer (score 0):

You are using cPanel so you will have to add your ISP ip in remote mysql access list to access your mysql databases from your local PC.

Login your cPanel >> Database >> Remote MySQL >> Add your ISP IP

If you are still facing same issues then contact your hosting provider and ask them to enable mysql port in server firewall.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that mysql are hearing to internet. From you local server 95.218.172.137 run telnet `remote_server_or_remote_ip 3306`. If telnet show timeout, your server block 3306 (Put 3306 or Port used by mysql if you are changed this port) port. It's a firewall question.
2. If point 1 show a `"Connected to "` but can't work your program verify that user are on mysql.user table, with permission for acces from local server IP. You can see this on shell with mysql command.

   $ mysql
   mysql> SELECT Host,user FROM mysql.user WHERE `User` LIKE 'user_mysql';

On Cpanel user, you must see, edit or add, GLOBAL permision for all users of this account to access mysql server, usin IP, or IP plus comodin %. If you add a IP or wildcard IP all your user on this account has permission to access remotely orm this Ip or one IP of range wildcard. Also you can verify this with

```
$ mysql 
mysql> SELECT Host,user FROM mysql.user WHERE `Host` LIKE 'IP';
```